# How can I access my Express API with my Typescript NextJS code?

Tags: typescript, express, next.js

I am trying to get data from my API which is returning the following JSON:

```js
[
  { project: "Challenges_jschallenger.com" },
  { project: "Using-Studio-Ghilis-API-With-JS-Only" },
  { project: "my-portfolio-next" },
  { project: "Youtube-Navbar-2021" },
  { project: "Mana-raWozonWebsite" },
  { project: "Movies-Website" },
  { project: "Add-Remove-Mark-and-Mark-off-With-ReactJS" },
  { project: "My-Portfolio" },
  { project: "Github_Explorer" },
  { project: "MestreALMO.github.io" },
  { project: "Tests-With-useState-useEffect-useRef" },
  { project: "Tic-Tac-Toe-React-in-JS" },
  { project: "ReactJS-with-TypeScript-Template" },
  { project: "Retractable-Accordion" },
]
```

And I'm trying to use it in my NextJS code below:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/");
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { projects: data },
  };
};

interface interfaceProjects {
  project: string;
}

const Landing = (projects: interfaceProjects) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      {console.log(projects)}
      {/* {projects.map((project) => (
        <h3>project</h3>
      ))} */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Landing;
```

My `projects.map` was returning the error: `TypeError: projects.map is not a function`. So I coded the `console.log(projects)` and it returned empty. How can I fix this so the `projects.map` starts to work? What did I do wrong?

If anyone want to see the code working I created a github page for this code. The api is in the `express-api` folder. https://github.com/MestreALMO/NextJS-Testing-Express-API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up making it work here is the full code of the solution:

```js
import { InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next";

type Post = {
  project: string;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/");
  const posts: Post[] = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};

function Blog({ posts }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Hi</h3>
      {console.log(posts)}
    </>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`const Landing = (projects: interfaceProjects) => {`

To:

`const Landing = (projects: interfaceProjects[]) => {`

To fix the type error.

Also is the function getStaticProps ever getting called?

Comment: those are good points, though I can't figure it out where to call ```getStaticProps``` in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

Answer (score 0):

Types aside, your Landing function actually receives `props`, not `projects`. Here's a verbose example how to get `projects`:

```
const Landing = (props) => {

  const projects = props.projects;
  console.log(projects); // This logs to the server console

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>

      {/* This logs to the browser console */}
      {console.log(projects)}

    </>
  );
};
```

However, you should still see the `props` object in the console. Make sure you're looking at the right one, since in your code you're logging on client side.

Comment: I tryed it after you said, but it does not work. the props are still empty.

Comment: Here's a working example with a test API call: https://replit.com/@AlexAntsiferov/getStaticPropsEmpty